# Sketchup is not recognizing extensions in 'plugins' directory

Tags: windows, sketchup

I recently had to reinstall the OS on one of my systems, along with all of it's software; I have installed my copy of Sketchup Pro 2018, and it works without issue.

Since I no longer have many of the plugins I frequently use in their original `.rbz` format, I've copied the contents of my old installation's `...\appdata\roaming\sketchup\plugins` folder into that of the current installation. While this should work in theory, none of the plugins are present when I start up the software.

What might I be missing, and how can this be resolved? I have tried compressing the individual plugins into `.rbz` archives and installing them through Sketchup but nothing happens upon completion of this action. Extension loading policy is set to 'unrestricted.' I have configured exceptions in Windows 10's 'protected folder access' for the software. These are just about the only routes of troubleshooting I have considered, and since I have no way to re-download the plugins I require, I am out of options.

Thank you all for any suggestions or answers!

Comment: Sorry, but tech support is generally off-topic here on GDSE. You might get a quicker answer in the [Sketchup forum](https://forums.sketchup.com/).

Comment: I kinda thought that would be the case- Figured I'd ask anyways as I'd received assistance in similar issues previously. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you need to manually re-add them as add-ons from the relevant section of the preferences.

Comment: This is Google's /Trimble's stance on the issue, also part of the issue I am experiencing... Since I no longer have many of the plugins in their original .RBZ format this is not possible, and means repurchasing some plugins. This did work at some point before, not now, unfortunately